# Css, circles animation how to have them growing on hover and staying on the same line

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've 2 problems with the following snippet, I would like that on hover all the circles stay on the same line, they are "simply" pushed on the side.

But I'm struggling, it only seems they are going to the bottom when one of the circle is scaling..

Then, I'm trying to have them as close as possible, maybe because it's not aline, but they don't stick together on resize. And the text move too far away :O

I've seen the scaling option but I can't make it work here. So I'm only using the font-size.

I'm really not good with animations, if someone could give me clues or help me with that I would be grateful!

```css
.bubble {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.bubble p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(100, 110, 115, 0.6);
}

.circle:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 80px;
  transition: font 0.5s ease;
  transform-origin: 0 0
}

.label-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.label-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.circle.blue:before {
  color: #306BCE;
}
.circle.azure:before {
  color: #05CDF9;
}
.circle.yellow:before {
  color: #EEFB11;
}
.circle.red:before {
  color: red;
}
.circle.bordeau:before {
  color: #C90035;
}
.circle.purple:before {
  color: #832A50;
}
.circle.brown:before {
  color: #6C000C;
}

.circle:hover:before {
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle blue"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Honesty</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Confidence</p>
    <span class="circle azure"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle yellow"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Curiosity</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Passion</p>
    <span class="circle red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle bordeau"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Judging</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Disagree</p>
    <span class="circle purple"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle brown"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Nervousness</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well messing with the font-size is a large part of your problem here ... because that changes the properties of the whole “line” those elements are on, and therefor it is only natural things start to “jump”. You could perhaps avoid that, if you positioned the circles absolute ... but using a scale transformation would make much more sense here, because that eliminates the problem to begin with, since it does not change the space the element takes up.

Comment: Thank you for that CBroe, I'll try! 
Thus you think that the way the circles are created is ok?

Comment: @JayCee You want circle to be on top and move increased circle to the bottom?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov When you are on hover the circle should grow and push right / left other circles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As what @CBroe has pointed out, you are using a font glyph as the circle. By changing its font size, you are changing the line-height and that will mess up the vertical positioning of all elements in the row. The trick is to use pseudo-elements to create the circles instead, and position the circles absolutely. Once that is done, you can use `transform: scale(...)` to scale up the circles, without affecting the layout of surrounding elements.

I have also made some changes to your code:

- Using `display: flex` to align your bubble elements. You may also use `float: left` on the bubble elements, but flexbox is quite widely supported today.
- Do not set the transform origin, because it defaults to `center center` anyway :)

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 90px;
}

.bubble p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(100, 110, 115, 0.6);
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.circle:before {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: ' ';
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}

.label-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.label-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.circle.blue:before {
  background-color: #306BCE;
}

.circle.azure:before {
  background-color: #05CDF9;
}

.circle.yellow:before {
  background-color: #EEFB11;
}

.circle.red:before {
  background-color: red;
}

.circle.bordeau:before {
  background-color: #C90035;
}

.circle.purple:before {
  background-color: #832A50;
}

.circle.brown:before {
  background-color: #6C000C;
}

.circle:hover:before {
  transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle blue"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Honesty</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Confidence</p>
    <span class="circle azure"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle yellow"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Curiosity</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Passion</p>
    <span class="circle red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle bordeau"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Judging</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Disagree</p>
    <span class="circle purple"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle brown"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Nervousness</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**: If you want the width of the element to expand on hover, that is also possible. However, I also suggest that you can simplify your markup: basically we can make do without the circle div:

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 90px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.bubble p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(100, 110, 115, 0.6);
}

.bubble:before {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: ' ';
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.label-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.label-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bubble.blue:before {
  background-color: #306BCE;
}

.bubble.azure:before {
  background-color: #05CDF9;
}

.bubble.yellow:before {
  background-color: #EEFB11;
}

.bubble.red:before {
  background-color: red;
}

.bubble.bordeau:before {
  background-color: #C90035;
}

.bubble.purple:before {
  background-color: #832A50;
}

.bubble.brown:before {
  background-color: #6C000C;
}

.bubble:hover {
  width: calc(40px * 2.5);
}
.bubble:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  <div class="bubble blue">
    <p class="label-bottom">Honesty</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble azure">
    <p class="label-top">Confidence</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble yellow">
    <p class="label-bottom">Curiosity</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble red">
    <p class="label-top">Passion</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble bordeau">
    <p class="label-bottom">Judging</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble purple">
    <p class="label-top">Disagree</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble brown">
    <p class="label-bottom">Nervousness</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Holy shit, it's super fluid! Thank you for that. I know need to figure out how to have other circles not being overlap.

Comment: @JayCee If you don't want to circles to overlap, you can adjust the width of the `.bubble` parent when hovering.

Comment: When you talk about the width when hovering, is it like managing all hover from the parent instead of the span directly?

Comment: @JayCee Please see the second code snippet in the updated answer ;) you can actually simplify your markup by quite a bit.

Comment: You're awesome! Why didn't I thought of simply stop using the span and using directly the div... If you ever come to London I'll pay you a drink. Or 2.

Answer (score 2):

I've used @Terry's excellent answer as the base to mine.

The main difference is that you don't need the pseudo elements. Just `transform: scale()` (transforms don't effect the layout) the hovered elements, and give it `z-index: 1` *if you want* to bring them to the top.

```css
.bubble-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 90px;
}

.bubble p {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(100, 110, 115, 0.6);
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40x;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: ' ';
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.label-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.label-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.circle.blue {
  background-color: #306BCE;
}

.circle.azure {
  background-color: #05CDF9;
}

.circle.yellow {
  background-color: #EEFB11;
}

.circle.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.circle.bordeau {
  background-color: #C90035;
}

.circle.purple {
  background-color: #832A50;
}

.circle.brown {
  background-color: #6C000C;
}

.circle:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(2.5);
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-wrapper">
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle blue"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Honesty</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Confidence</p>
    <span class="circle azure"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle yellow"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Curiosity</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Passion</p>
    <span class="circle red"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle bordeau"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Judging</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <p class="label-top">Disagree</p>
    <span class="circle purple"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bubble">
    <span class="circle brown"></span>
    <p class="label-bottom">Nervousness</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like both your ideas, right now I'm trying Terry's idea not to have the circle overlapping, I'm having a hell of a time haha. (feeling ashamed)

Comment: @JayCee - enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.bubble {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /* margin-right: -17px; */
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle:hover:before {
    /* font-size: 200px; */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.circle.blue:before {
    background: #306BCE;
    /* width: 50px; */
    /* height: 50px; */
    /* display: block; */
}

.circle:before {
    content: '';
    font-size: 80px;
    transition: font 0.5s ease;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: play with transition property